What is the name of this World War II movie?
Can anyone identify this World War II movie for me?
This is an American war movie and was probably made sometime in the 1960s. It is the story of a young boy who after losing his parents is taken in by a family of Japanese descent. The family is able to teach this young man Japanese during the years he stayed with them.
When war breaks out he tries to join the army (marines?), but is (I believe) denied because of some medical condition (hearing?). Once they become aware that he able to speak and understand Japanese, he is enlisted immediately! 
The only scene that I am able to recall is when the US troops are engaged in fighting on an island in the Pacific and when a Japanese officer orders his men to shoot the Americans, instead of laying down their arms. As a result of this conversation he kills some of the enemy troops who were unaware that understood their language! 
I believe that this movie was in color, but it may have been in black and white.

Sound like Hell to Eternity (1960)

True life story of Guy Gabaldon, a Los Angeles Hispanic boy raised in
  the 1930s by a Japanese-American foster family. Later, during the war,
  as his foster parents are interned at a camp for Japanese Americans,
  Gabaldon's ability to speak Japanese helps him become a lone-operating
  Marine hero. During the bloody capture of the island of Saipan, he
  convinces 800 Japanese to surrender after their general commits
  suicide.

